# Will creating an SQL table that already exists overwrite it?

Tags: sql, database

Very simply:

If I create a table in a database, will it delete or overwrite another table of the same name?

I have a script in a game that needs a table of information.
Can I simply run this every time the script starts?:

```
CREATE TABLE player_data ( UniqueID string, Money int )
```

So that when someone else runs the script on their game, the table will be created, but if they run it again, it wont be overwritten?

Comment: On the database engine's I've used, attempting to (re)create an already existing table will cause an error.

Comment: I'd be very wary of a database that *didn't* treat this as an error.

Comment: @KenWhite In retrospect, that's a really good point. Sorry for the spam :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on which database engine you are using. In MySQL there's `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to make it will only try to create the table if it does not already exist.

So your statement would look like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_data ( UniqueID string, Money int )`. If there was no table named player_data then a new table would be created. However if there was already a table named player_data then no modifications would occur to the database.

There are usually alternatives for most popular Database Engines to do something similar.

Comment: But `IF NOT EXISTS` is something you have to *explicitly* provide. I think the OP is concerned with *accidentally* overwriting an existing table.

Comment: The first time the table will not exist and the player_data table will be created with the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_data ( UniqueID string, Money int )` however the next time this statement will run there will be no table modifications or creations since the table already exists. I'll update my answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 7):

> but if they run it again, it wont be overwritten?

No. In general you have to DROP the table first before CREATE succeeds.

There are lots of exceptions to this when it comes to actual implementations, such as if the table is temporary or permanent, access rights where multiple users can have the same table name as long as they all use different user names. Look in your particular server version for such exceptions.